# Graphic intensive application virtualization/TS

Tags: virtualization, terminal, application, graphics

I am looking to have graphically intensive applications such as Pro/Engineer and Ansys (CAD type software) published in some way to run on servers instead of the workstations for remote work.  My experience so far has been with Terminal Server and also with TS remoteapp which just don't cut it for graphically intensive applications. Is application virtualization allowing for better graphics to be passed seamlessly to the client?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your only option for remote 3D rendering is MS RemoteFX with Session Virtualization. It *has* to be over a LAN, and your apps must be able to use Direct3d rather than OpenGL.

On the server side you need to be stacking the server with Quadro cards on the hardware compatability list (there's only 3 or 4 of them).

Be aware the solution isn't particularly cheap, scalable, or mature.

Comment: Thanks, guess we'll just have to wait for the technology to get there.

Comment: The RemoteFX solution is pretty VRAM heavy (220MB per monitor/VM) but the performance is great. I have it running on a server with a Quadro 880 (not on the supported list) so I suspect other cards will be certified soon.

Answer (score 1):

Does not work at the moment. Better with Cytrix and / or the upcoming 2008 R2 Sp1 which has new codecs and supposedly is good enough to handle even stuff like 3d over RDP (though I have no idea what the bandwidth requirement will be - can be this is a LAN only thing).

That said, the area is pretty grey. I am successfully using multiple virtual machines in a hosting center and remote my graphics from there - and we talk about doing VS 2010 development work and / or multi screen financial trading applications. Works without a flaw there. Did NOT work so well with older windows versions.